# Reading prototype variable with easeljs click event

Tags: javascript, prototype, easeljs

I'm quite new to JS's prototypying but not to oop in general. New to easeljs, however.
Having said that, i've been trying to get an object variable triggered by a click event, and i REALLY can't seem to find a decent way of doing it.

Trying to build a clickable 2D "board", here is my test code:

```
(function() { //"Class"

        Brick = function() {
            this.initialize();
        };

        var p = Brick.prototype = new createjs.Container();
        p.Container_initialize = p.initialize;

        p.initialize = function() {
            this.Container_initialize();
        };

        p.create = function(row, column) {
            this.row = row;
            this.column = column;

            //Shape
            this.square = new createjs.Shape();
            this.square.graphics.beginFill("green").drawRect(0, 0, brickSize, brickSize);
            this.x = (brickSize * column) + (Game.padding * column); // Add some padding
            this.y = (brickSize * row) + (Game.padding * row); // Add some padding
            this.addChild(this.square);

            this.addEventListener("click", function(event) { console.log(this.row)})                
        };

    })();
```

After this I just create a few Bricks cycling through a multidimensional array cycle, and add them to the stage. The board shows perfectly, however, i keep getting "undefined" while cliking. console.log(event.currentTarget.row) works though, but not sure it's the way to go.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to create an instance of Parent to set the prototype of Child, use Object.create and shim it for older browsers:

```
var p = Brick.prototype = Object.create(createjs.Container.prototype);
```

Your event handler has the wrong value for `this`. The `this` value is the invoking object and is determined when invoking the function not when declaring it. You can fix that in the following way:

```
    p.create = function(row, column) {
        //.... not changed
        var me = this;
        this.addEventListener("click", function(event) { 
          console.log(me.row)})                
    };
```

If you use Chrome or Firefox with firebug it's sometimes better to just `console.log(this)` and click on the logged item for closer inspection.

More info about prototype can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941).